# A dance party is happening on a world with 3 genders: snails, pre-snails and post-snails. There are 8 aliens of each gender at the party.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A dance party is happening on a world with 3 genders: snails, pre-snails and
post-snails. There are 8 aliens of each gender at the party. How many ways
can the aliens be divided up into triples to dance 1 if, as is the custom on this
planet, each triple consists of one snail, one pre-snail, and one post-snail?

I think the answer should be 8*8*8 
but i am not sure

Comment: @William  The answer posted by joriki is correct.  The idea here is to line up the snails in some order, then assign dance partners to those snails from each of the other genders.

Answer (score 3):

The pre-snails can be assigned to the snails in $8!$ different ways, and so can the post-snails, for a total of $8!^2=1625702400$ different configurations.